# Add primary key to the table coulmn(please see the attached image for more clarity)

Tags: sql-server

Creating table without using SQL table feature:

[image]
I'm trying to create table going to "Tables","Create Table" feature. How do I add primary and unique keys using this feature.

Comment: Images are really frowned upon by the community, as they don't help others help you as easily; especially those with screen readers. You would be far better off, for something like this giving us the DDL of your table and then showing us what you've tried and explaining why it didn't work. If you haven't tried anything, show us what in the documentation (or Search Engine searches) you read and what you didn't understand so we can further explain it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the selected column and set the option primary key from the context menu.

It has been shown below.

[image]

Comment: That is a *very* old version of SSMS you have there, Suraj .

Comment: @Larnu It is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Ouch, why not use a supported version? (Realise we're off topic here, but...)

Comment: @Larnu That is in the process of the update (in my company). However, I do use latest version at least 2012 in personal computer.

Comment: The latest version of SSMS is version 18.4 though, not 2012 ;)

Comment: @Larnu I mean the version of SSMS which comes with SQL Server 2012 integrated and installs automatically by installing SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Yes, thats SSMS 2012. SSMS 18 has been available for the best part of a year, so just odd to see someone that's using an unsupported version.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation covers this nicely: From [Create Primary Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15)

> ### Using SQL Server Management Studio
>
> To create a primary key
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, right-click the table to which you want to add a unique constraint, and click Design.
> 2. In Table Designer, click the row selector for the database column you want to define as the primary key. If you want to select multiple
>      columns, hold down the CTRL key while you click the row selectors for
>      the other columns.
> 3. Right-click the row selector for the column and select Set Primary Key.

Or, if you want to use Transact-sQL

> ### Using Transact-SQL
>
> **To create a primary key in an existing table**
>
> The following example creates a primary key on the column
>   TransactionID in the AdventureWorks database.
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE Production.TransactionHistoryArchive
>       ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TransactionHistoryArchive_TransactionID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TransactionID);
> ```

It also goes on to explain how you can use T-SQL to create a `NONCLUSTERED` Primary key, and then add a further `CLUSTERED INDEX` on the table:

> **To create a primary key with clustered index in a new table**
>
> The following example creates a table and defines a primary key on the
>   column CustomerID and a clustered index on TransactionID in the
>   AdventureWorks database.
>
> ```
> -- Create table to add the clustered index
> CREATE TABLE Production.TransactionHistoryArchive1
>    (
>       CustomerID uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()
>       , TransactionID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
>       , CONSTRAINT PK_TransactionHistoryArchive1_CustomerID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (CustomerID)
>    )
> ;
>
> -- Now add the clustered index
> CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_TransactionID ON Production.TransactionHistoryArchive1 (TransactionID);
> ```